# Compare 2 files on 2 different branches on GIT

Tags: git, windows-8.1

I have to compare 2 files on 2 different branches on GIT.After that I need to merge it to master.

I saw this :

`git diff branch1:full/path/to/foo.txt branch2:full/path/to/foo-another.txt`

Can you tell me how to fill the full path and branch1 and branch2 ?

**Update :** I tried like this.But it's not working.Can you tell me why ?

```
git diff 
master:https://github.com/MyGit/blob/master/My.Web/App/tenant/views/propertymana
gement/index.less access-ui:https://github.com/MyGit/blob/access-
ui/My.Web/App/tenant/views/propertymanagement/index.less
```

Above command gives this **error** :

```
fatal: Path 'https://github.com/MyGit/blob/master/My.Web/App/t
enant/views/propertymanagement/index.less' does not exist in 'master'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me how to fill the full path and branch1 and branch2 ?

It is a relative path to your current path in **work tree**, not a URI for file.

For a local work tree with two folder dir1 and dir2, you are now in dir1 and want to compare files in dir1, use the following command:

```
git diff branch1:file1.c branch2:file1
```

To compare files in dir2, use the following command.

```
git diff branch1:../dir2/file2.c branch2:../dir2/file2.c
```

You can compare files with different filename in different folder too, i.e, the following command is ok.

```
git diff branch1:file1.c branch2:../dir2/file2.c
```

Answer (score 0):

`git diff yourbranch1 yourbranch2 -- yourfile.txt`

or use meld or whatever your git diff tool is.

Comment: Can you see my Update above and give an example using those names ?

Comment: git diff master access-ui -- full/path/to/foo.txt

Comment: what is the `full/path` ? Can you simulate it using my example above ?

Comment: Your command gives this error because git has to now what file you are referring to. If you are in the git project folder you can easily do "git diff master access-ui -- index.less".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the full path, but the path relative to the relevant tree.

From [git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) documentation:

```
 git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…​]

   This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
```

Use:

```
git diff master access-ui My.Web/App/tenant/views/propertymanagement/index.less
```

Comment: It gives this error : `fatal: ambiguous argument 'access-ui': unknown revision or path not in the worki
ng tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: It looks like there is no local branch named access-ui, is it true?

Comment: If it is a remote branch you need to either check it out locally first or refer to it's remote location, like `origin/access-ui`.